# CSS iPad issue with float?

Tags: html, iphone, css, ipad

I am having a css issue on the ipad with this site: http://heyheyandco.com/

In a browser the social media icons are on the right but on an ipad or iphone its to the right, but not all the way to the right, anything I can do to fix this? here is my code for the social media div:

```
.social-media {
float: right;
width: 98px;
margin-left: -180px !important;
}
```

and additional css code:

```
.site {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 1200px;
overflow: hidden;
}

body .site {
padding: 0 40px;
padding: 0 2.857142857rem;
margin-bottom: 48px;
margin-bottom: 3.428571429rem;
box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.3);
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Mate can you put it in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: its a wordpress site, that would take forever, you can look at the url

Comment: My solution is to use CSS media queries for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries.

Answer (score 1):

Need to add the viewport meta tag to your html head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Whoa sorry about that, didnt scroll down. You're going to need to use media queries to 'shrink' the width of all the body content. A short / amazing book on media queries: http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design .. Good luck!